# styling google-map-react map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-react

I am building a map with `google-map-react` and trying to style it with no luck. I am using the documentation here: https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react/blob/master/API.md and adding styles via a prop called `options` like it says but I am not seeing any styles being applied.

Here is my code:

```js
const createMapOptions = () => {
  return {
    styles: [{stylers: [{'saturation': -100}, {'gamma': 0.2}, {'lightness': 4}, {'visibility': 'on'}]}]
  }
}

const Map = ({center, children, onGoogleApiLoaded, useGoogleMapsApis, zoom}) => {

  return (
    <div className='h-100p w-100p'>
      <GoogleMap
        bootstrapURLKeys={{key: '...'}}
        defaultCenter={center}
        defaultZoom={zoom}
        options={createMapOptions}
        yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={useGoogleMapsApis}
        onGoogleApiLoaded={onGoogleApiLoaded}
      >
        {children}
      </GoogleMap>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Any guidance on how to get **ANY** styling applied would be greatly appreciated.

**Note** - I am using a developer key, not sure if that could be why I am not seeing the styling?

**Also Note** - I do not want tips on `react-google-maps` a similar library, but not the same as `google-map-react`. Ive seen other `google-map-react` questions answered and up voted with people referring to `react-google-maps`.

Answer (score 0):

Some times styling in react as difficult when you use packages. So the Best Way to do it is

1. Open Inspect Element in your browser
2. Select the Particular Element whose styling you want to modify.
3. Copy the class that is used in it already.
4. Make changes to the same css className in your own scss or css file and will modify.

Note : If nothing Happens Try using the !important in the property.

Comment: This did not answer my question at all

Comment: can you please use 
https://codesandbox.io/s/new for your react code and be precise about what exactly you want your styling to be like ?

Comment: `Any guidance on how to get ANY styling applied would be greatly appreciated.`

Comment: Please use a the sandbox for react and tell what exactly you want to change. 
While using packages there are many different ways of doing a task when it comes to styling of components from packages. 
You need to changes a few things in module if needed.

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlOptions

Use this as resource to change css for the package.

Screenshot from the the above resource
[image]